# wrapper function for axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How to make a wrapper function for axios

I want to return axios from a function so that if my project switch to another fetch api it can easily done

I'm doing something like this

```
 import axios from 'axios'
export function apiCall(){
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-CSRFToken": "example-of-custom-header"
    };
    return axios

 }
```

and in all actions i'm using something this

```
import apiCall from './somepath

function fetchContent(){
  return apiCall.get('http://localhost:3003/')
}
```

but I'm getting `TypeError: _ApiCall__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.get is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things wrong with this code.

1. It should be `apicCall().get` since `apiCall` is a function.
2. Since you're using a non-default export you should use `import {apiCall} from './somepath'`

However here's how I suggest you do this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-CSRFToken": "example-of-custom-header"
};
export default axios;
```

This way you can do:

```
import axios from './somepath'
```

and then use the axios api as normal since that would be the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Try `return apiCall().get('...')` - emphasis on the extra parenthesis after `apiCall()`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the axios wrapper module as you've defined it, you'll need to invoke `apiCall` as a function like so:

```
import apiCall from './somepath

function fetchContent(){
  /* Add () after apiCall */
  return apiCall().get('http://localhost:3003/')
}
```